# Adding Two accounts in outlook 2007 connected to exchange

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to configure two accounts in Microsoft outlook 2007 connected to the same exchange server/same domain. First account is configured associated with the user but when I try to configure the second account it is giving an error :

**unable to connect to IMAP server.**

Can anyone assist me to how to configure the same or it is supported by Microsoft outlook 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAP accounts are supported in Outlook 2007. The error message indicates a connection problem with the server, or incorrect configuration values.  You must also ensure that IMAP connections are supported on your Exchange server.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, IMAP connection is supported by the exchange server. Is it possible to configure two e-mail accounts connected with the same exchange server.

Comment: You can't have multiple Exchange mailboxes in the same profile unless you have Outlook 2010 or greater. Are you trying to add one Exchange account and one IMAP account to the SAME Mailbox??  If not, there's no reason why you can't have two IMAP accounts configured to access two different Mailboxes on your Exchange server.

Comment: Actually one exchange account is already configured for that user and want to add one more account with the same domain. Anyways thank you for clarifying.